# Varnish not caching simple GET request to backend

Tags: api, nginx, caching, get, varnish

I'm experimenting with Varnish 6.0.3 as a caching server community version installed on a CentOS 7.6.

I deploy Varnish behind an NGINX, working as SSL offload and proxy. The Varnish server sends requests to another NGINX (Kubernetes ingress controller) that prox again to a JAVA SpringBoot backend.

[image: Deployment schema]

The NGINX front off Varnish is configured as follow:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name cache.mydomain.io;
    ssl_certificate /opt/ssl/my.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/ssl/my.key;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/cache.mydomain.io-access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass          http://10.100.0.7:6081;

    }
}
```

I'm using Varnish with a very default configuration:

```
backend default {
    .host = "10.100.16.128";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

After this, I started sending requests as follow:

```
curl 'https://cache.mydomain.io/health'
{"status":"UP"}
```

and I'm able to see the request follow all the chain, from NGINX to Varnish and the JAVA backend.
But trying again and again with the same GET request, I never have a cache HIT on Varnish side. All the request are miss and served from the backend according to the varnishstat cmd.

```
Uptime mgt:  0+00:22:30                                                     Hitrate n:   10  100      133
Uptime child:    0+00:22:31                                                        avg(n):   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000

    NAME                               CURRENT        CHANGE       AVERAGE        AVG_10       AVG_100      AVG_1000 
MGT.uptime                          0+00:22:30
MAIN.uptime                         0+00:22:31
MAIN.sess_conn                              37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.client_req                             37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.cache_hitmiss                          35          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.22      0.23
MAIN.cache_miss                             37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.backend_conn                            2          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.01      0.01
MAIN.backend_reuse                          35          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.22      0.23
MAIN.backend_recycle                        37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.fetch_chunked                          37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.pools                                   2          0.00           .            2.00          2.00      2.00
MAIN.threads                               200          0.00           .          200.00        200.00        200.00
MAIN.threads_created                       200          0.00          0.15          0.00          0.00      0.00
MAIN.n_object                                1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00      1.00
MAIN.n_objectcore                            1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00      1.00
MAIN.n_objecthead                            3          0.00           .            3.00          2.93      2.92
MAIN.n_backend                               1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00      1.00
MAIN.n_expired                               1          0.00          0.00          0.00          0.00      0.00
MAIN.s_sess                                 37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.s_fetch                                37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.s_req_hdrbytes                       7.37K         0.00          5.59          0.00         47.23         49.35
MAIN.s_resp_hdrbytes                     31.26K         0.00         23.70          0.01        200.29        209.30
MAIN.s_resp_bodybytes                      555          0.00          0.41          0.00          3.47      3.63
MAIN.sess_closed                            37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.backend_req                            37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
MAIN.n_vcl                                   1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00      1.00
MAIN.bans                                    1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00      1.00
SMA.s0.g_space                          256.00M         0.00           .          256.00M   256.00M       256.00M
SMA.Transient.c_req                        111          0.00          0.08          0.00          0.69      0.73
SMA.Transient.c_bytes                   624.05K         0.00        473.00          0.29          3.90K     4.08K
SMA.Transient.c_freed                   623.20K         0.00        472.36          0.29          3.90K     4.07K
SMA.Transient.g_alloc                        1          0.00           .            1.00          1.00      1.00
SMA.Transient.g_bytes                      872          0.00           .          872.00        872.00        872.00
VBE.boot.default.bereq_hdrbytes           8.54K         0.00          6.47          0.00         54.75         57.22
VBE.boot.default.beresp_hdrbytes         29.16K         0.00         22.10          0.01        186.84        195.24
VBE.boot.default.beresp_bodybytes          555          0.00          0.41          0.00          3.47      3.63
VBE.boot.default.req                        37          0.00          0.03          0.00          0.23      0.24
```

Can you help me understand what's going wrong with my actual configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Actually moved to cache using NGINX, as documented here: https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-caching
works really fine.